# document scopes with JSDOC

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsdoc

I`m having difficult times to documents scopes with JSDOC, anyone can tell what is the right way to document the following code :

(Right now, jsdoc generates all the methods in GLOBAL functions and they should belong to the WorkAreaPlugin )

```
/**
 * @namespaces Retalix.StoreOfficeClient.Web.Scripts.General.WorkArea
 * @scope WorkAreaPlugin
 */
(function ($, undefined) {

/**
 * Description
 * @constructor
 * @method ctor
 * @param {} options     
 * @return 
 */
var ctor = function (options) {
    var self = this;
    var _data;
    var _new;
    var _grids = {};

    if (this.setupAjaxCrud) {
        this.setupAjaxCrud();
    }

    $.extend(self,
        {
        /**
         * Sets the data property of the current scope and setups the set_isDirty and the get_isDirty functions if not exist to the data object 
         * @method set_data
         * @param {} data
         * @param {} triggerChange
         * @return 
         */
        set_data: function (data, triggerChange) {
            _data = data || {};
            if (!_data.set_isDirty) {
                $.setupDirtyFunctions(_data);
            }
            if (triggerChange !== false) {
                self.trigger("dataChanged", [_data, self]);
            }
        }
    });

    this.bind("login", function () {
        var isDirty = self.isDirty();
        if (!isDirty && self.loader && $.isFunction(self.loader.doLoading)) {
            self.reload();
        }
    });
};

StoreOfficeClient.Plugins.Register("workArea", undefined, undefined, ctor);

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: What version of jsdoc are you using? I don't recall ever seeing `@scope` documented for the 3.x series. (But the documentation is sometimes deficient.)

Comment: I`m using jsdoc3.3.0 , I`ve seen the @scope option here : https://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/DocExamples#Changing_Scope but it doesnt work for me . how would you document this ?  (even without the @scope)

Comment: The doc you've seen there is for jsdoc 2.x.

Comment: ok, so how to recommend to do this ?

Comment: Oops. Forgot to mention this earlier. Don't use jsdoc 3.3.0, as it is still alpha and buggy, please use the latest in the 3.2.x series. (And I presume you've seen that I've submitted an answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Let me preface by pointing out that documenting JavaScript code with jsdoc often boils down to a matter of convention and how you want to present the relationship between JS entities to the people reading the documentation. So the following is *one* possible answer.

The following would put everything in a single namespace:

```
/**
 * @namespace Retalix.StoreOfficeClient.Web.Scripts.General.WorkArea.WorkAreaPlugin
 *
 */
(/** @lends Retalix.StoreOfficeClient.Web.Scripts.General.WorkArea.WorkAreaPlugin */ function ($, undefined) {

/**
 * Description
 * @constructor
 * @param {} options
 */
var ctor = function (options) {
    var self = this;
    var _data;
    var _new;
    var _grids = {};

    if (this.setupAjaxCrud) {
        this.setupAjaxCrud();
    }

    $.extend(self,
             /** @lends Retalix.StoreOfficeClient.Web.Scripts.General.WorkArea.WorkAreaPlugin~ctor# */ {
        /**
         * Sets the data property of the current scope and setups the set_isDirty and the get_isDirty functions if not exist to the data object
         * @param {} data
         * @param {} triggerChange
         */
        set_data: function (data, triggerChange) {
            _data = data || {};
            if (!_data.set_isDirty) {
                $.setupDirtyFunctions(_data);
            }
            if (triggerChange !== false) {
                self.trigger("dataChanged", [_data, self]);
            }
        }
    });

    this.bind("login", function () {
        var isDirty = self.isDirty();
        if (!isDirty && self.loader && $.isFunction(self.loader.doLoading)) {
            self.reload();
        }
    });
};

StoreOfficeClient.Plugins.Register("workArea", undefined, undefined, ctor);

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: jsdoc outputs it like ctor is a class (under Classes there is ctor) and ctor is only the constructor. Also, i don't want it to be called classes, is there any chance that i can tell jsdoc that WorkAreaPlugin is a plugin inside the above namespcae ?

Comment: jsdoc does not make a difference between the concepts of "constructor" and "class". See the documentation on [`@constructor`](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-constructor.html): a synonym for it is `@class`. And jsdoc has no concept of a "plugin". You could make `ctor` and `set_data` be regular functions of a namespace that corresponds to your plugin.